# Component Below Flatlist doens't appear

Tags: javascript, react-native

I've been trying to make a simple app, and I want some comment section that I create with flatlist, but after I create some component below my flatlist it won't appear, but the height of it appears, it just the component itself won't appear, after I'm trying to comment my flatlist, the component below it showed up.

Can you give me solution for this problem? so stuck with it

```
<View
     style={{
     alignItems: 'center',
     flex: 1,
     }}>
     <FlatList
       data={Comment}
       keyExtractor={Comment.id}
       renderItem={renderItem}
       removeClippedSubviews={true}
       scrollEnabled={false}
      />
   </View>
</View>
              
<View>
   <Timeline data={data} />
 </View>
</View>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: FlatList has support for this https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#listfootercomponent

Comment: what if i want to add a component outside the flatlist itself, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <View
    style={{
      alignItems: "center",
      flex: 1,
    }}
  >
    <FlatList
      data={Comment}
      keyExtractor={Comment.id}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      removeClippedSubviews={true}
      scrollEnabled={false}
    />
  </View>

  <View>
    <Timeline data={data} />
  </View>
</View>
```

Comment: @user14593851 Try out this

Comment: thanks for ur answer, but it still doesn't work:(